# Import Request Not working in modified GCP Cloud Function in Python

Tags: python, request, google-cloud-functions

We have a old Cloud Function written in Python on GCP. In it we were using importing "request" module. Reference is mentioned in requirements.txt.

Now we need to make a small change in code, however we are not able deploy the updated code. It is giving us error for "request" module.

Please advise if anyone has seen this earlier and suggested solution.

Comment: You will need to show us the code that is raising the error too. Do you maybe mean the `requests` module?

Comment: Can  you share the piece of code that doesn't work?

Comment: Am getting this error on CF deploy: <<Build failed: `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for request (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))

error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1; Error ID: 9E311351>>

Comment: Are you able to run the code locally?

Comment: Can you share with us how you're using `request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project http://pypi.org/p/request was removed by its author and no longer exists.

This was likely being used in error, instead of http://pypi.org/p/requests.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed Request to Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the case description you are not able to download "request", but I think you want "[requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)" (extra 's' at the end). Let me know if that worked out for you.

Comment: Yes, already tried this i.e. requests. it still does not get deployed. As I said, old code was working earlier when we deployed last in the month of Apr'2020. Now we want to make a small change and it is not getting deployed. Please advise.